# How to make another function aware of the loop name, so it can break it?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-of-loop

You see I have this code. (https://jsfiddle.net/kg4f2bu0/).

Inside my `iterate` function I use a label for my loop, because I want to break it if it meets a condition. The condition gets checked inside the callback function. I want to break the `for..of` loop inside my callback function (`compare`). But it doesn't recognise the statement label. How can I make the callback function aware of the loop name?

This is JavaScript code. You can read information on label name here: https://javascript.info/while-for#labels-for-break-continue

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const iterate = (arr, callback) => {
  search: for (const item of arr) {
    callback(item)
  }
}

const compare = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
  if (num === 4) {
    console.log("breaking");
    break search;
  }
}

iterate(myArr, compare)
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel by the way. Look at `some` and `find` (and even `includes`).

Comment: @CherryDT This is just a very simple example of what I want to achieve. I know how to achieve it, but I am wondering if what I am trying above is possible at all or not.

Comment: Even if it would be possible it would be a really bad idea. It would lead to hard to read and maintain code. If you or someone else later looks at your code and sees a label not used in that function it is then hard to judge if it is used and where. And for the break it would not be clear where it jumps to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot break out of a loop from inside another function. The reason for this is technical: the label for the `break` is resolved once, before your code starts running. So at runtime, it's just a simple "goto"; the JavaScript engine doesn't go hunting up the call stack for a function containing a matching label. (What if there's none? What if there are multiple?)

What you can do instead is return a boolean value that indicates whether the item was found, and thus whether the loop should break:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const iterate = (arr, callback) => {
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (callback(item)) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

const compare = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
  if (num === 4) {
    console.log("breaking");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

iterate(myArr, compare)
```

Comment: That does make sense. Your example would have been my other option of doing it, but I was kind of hoping that my way would have been possible *somehow*, at least it would have been convenient.

Comment: It would also have been confusing and error-prone, because it creates an implicit, hidden dependency between `iterate` and `compare`.

Comment: Yes, that would have been my second or follow-up question, on how to make the label name dynamic. I was just hoping for too much.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.every() to perform the loop.  As soon as False is returned, the looping ends.  Here is an example.

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const iterate = (arr, callback) => {
  search: arr.every(compare) 
}

const compare = (num) => {
  console.log(num);
  if (num === 4) {
    console.log("breaking");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

iterate(myArr, compare)
```

Comment: While true, this is not what I was asking for, as my question was specific about the label name.